# graph.SetValueExt not working 5% of the time

Tags: acumatica

I am adding APTran lines to an existing AP Invoice using the APInvoiceEntry graph.

I have a custom field on it called `UsrMAFORexCommissionNbr`, which I set with a string value after I insert the line but before I save the changes.

95% of the time my code works but in some cases the value has not been set on the line (the lines gets added ok but the custom field isnt set).

Here is the last bit of my code adding the transline:

```
transLine.TaskID = task.ID;
transLine = graph.Transactions.Insert(transLine);
graph.SetValueExt(graph.Transactions.View.Name, transLine, "UsrMAFORexCommissionNbr", invNbr);

cInvoice.Hold = false;
cInvoice = graph.Document.Update(cInvoice);

graph.Actions.PressSave();
```

Can anybody help me with why in some cases the line

```
graph.SetValueExt(graph.Transactions.View.Name, transLine, "UsrMAFORexCommissionNbr", invNbr);
```

will not save the value set when it saves?

Comment: Are you able to replicate the problem reliably? How do you know if it fails? I checked the source code of SetValueExt function and it will return silently if you call it with a field name that doesn't exist. Other cases are handled through an exception handler, which should log a warning visible in Help->Trace.

Comment: I know it fails because I am processing a lot of lines at a time and when I do a general enquiry I see lines that have been created by my process but dont have the custom field set where it should be.  I havent been able to reproduce it yet unfortunatly which I know doesnt help.  For the moment I have changed the call to use PXDatabase.Update instead hopefully that is more reliable for me

Comment: Actually there was a bug related to cache extensions and long run processes. Looks like it's your case. I think it should be fixed in the Acumatica 6.0u4 or so